# nginx don't host on root host on root/somename

Tags: nginx, conf

How do I get nginx to ignore requests on `http://127.0.0.1/` but hand out from my html directory on `http://127.0.0.1/somename` this will also need to be the same for the proxy for `/data/`

---

I have tried the below and only get a 404.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        #Do I need something in here regardless?
    }

    location /somename {
        root   ../html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }


    #reverse proxy for ie support
    #
    location /somename/data {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080/data/;
        proxy_set_header  host localhost;
    }

    # redirect error pages to the static pages /50x.html /40x.html
    error_page  404              /404.html;
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
        root   ../html;
    }

    location = /404.html {
        root   ../html;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
location / {
    return 404;
}

location /somename/ {
    alias  ../html/;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html
- http://nginx.org/r/alias
- http://nginx.org/r/return
- http://nginx.org/r/index
- http://nginx.org/r/location

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "ignore"? If you access `http://127.0.0.1/`, what behaviour do you want?

I think it reasonable that you get a 404 if you access a path for which your web server does not have a file to send back to the client.

Comment: Ah correct a 404 would be fine. However I also get a 404 for `http://127.0.0.1/somename` with the above config for `location  /somename`. If I set the same config for `location  /` I get my home page as I would expect.